# NavigationService.Navigate async behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and C#, yet tried few things and got stuck.
Created a window and a page which contains one button.
Now on click of that button, i am navigating to another page using NavigationService.Navigate, passing a string data along.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new BaseWindow() , "Hello")
PostInit();
```

After my NavigationService_LoadCompleted is completed, i am setting a global vData, which i am using in PostInit(). But since it is an async call, my control is forwarded to PostInit before the navigation is completed and hence i am getting vData as null.

Can anyone guide me a correct process to achieve this. Any callback or something equivalent in c#.

```
public class BaseWindow : NavigationWindow
    {

        private Object vData = null;
        public BaseWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationService.LoadCompleted += NavigationService_LoadCompleted;
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            Title = "Enter Input";
            Height = 450;
            Width = 600;
        }

        public Object GetData()
        {
            return vData;
        }

        private void NavigationService_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            string str = (string)e.ExtraData;
            vData = str;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hook up another event handler and call `PostInit` in this one:

```
var baseWindow = new BaseWindow();
LoadCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
handler = (ss, ee) =>
{
    baseWindow.NavigationService.LoadCompleted -= handler;
    PostInit();
};
baseWindow.NavigationService.LoadCompleted += handler;
NavigationService.Navigate(baseWindow, "Hello");
```

Comment: Seems a bit hack , attaching and then detaching a delegate. But worked like a charm. Thanks :)